# Change UITableViewCell Height on Orientation Change

Tags: uitableview, resize, orientation

I have a UITableView with cells containing variable-height UILabels. I am able to calculate the minimum height the label needs to be using `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`, which works fine when the table view is first loaded. When I rotate the table view the cells become wider (meaning there are fewer lines required to display the content). Is there any way I can have the height of the cells redetermined by the UITableView during the orientation change animation or immediately before or after? Thank you.

Comment: How do you get the size (width) used for sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: ? I'm trying to make a variable-height cell that work for plain & grouped tableview style, but can't figure out how to get the width of the grouped tableview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your UITableViewController can implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method to specify the row height for a particular row, and it can look at the current orientation (`[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`) to decide what height to return.

To make sure `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called again when the orientation changes, you'll probably need to 
detect the orientation change as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995723/how-do-i-detect-a-rotation-on-the-iphone-without-the-device-autorotating), and call `[tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: I currently have `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` implemented, I didn't see it getting called on orientation change but it does get called on `reloadData` and I can detect the orientation change. If possible I'd like to have the height animate as the view rotates, but I'm not seeing that as a possibility.

Comment: According to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460014/can-you-animate-a-height-change-on-a-uitableviewcell-when-selected you might be able to do the animation by using `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` instead of `reloadData`

Comment: That works perfectly, David, thank you. I put this code in `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` and it works great. Right now it rotates and then resizes. I'm going to look for a better method to put this in and see if I can get it to resize as it rotates.

Answer (score 12):

To improve slightly on the answer above from @David and to answer the last comment about how to animate it smoothly during a rotation, use this method:

```
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

and of course the height delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
        return 171.0f;
    } else {
        return 128.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going insane! Any idea why statusBarOrientation works and orientation alone doesn't when you first initialize the app? Once running, and the orientation changes, both work fine.

Comment: UIDevice orientation and UIInterface orientation (from the statusBar) are not the same. UIDevice could be in UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp (ie your iPad sat flat on a table) - which doesn't tell you what the orientation of the interface is, which could be any of 4.