# iPad Orientation Checking UIView Class?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, orientation

I have a `UIView` class which I add to my main `UIViewController` and I need to check the orientation of the device (iPad) at the launch of the app, in the `viewDidLoad` method. However because the class is a `UIView` (not `UIViewController`) I can't use methods such as `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`.

So I attempted to use this in my `UIView` class:

```
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
    ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
```

However, testing with some breakpoints, whatever the orientation is, the of statement is never called, its skips right passed it. So what do you suggest I do to overcome this issue?

I need to somehow detect the orientation from the UIView class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you placing the check? The location could easily explain why it's not being called. To get rotation info, you could [register for a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995723/how-do-i-detect-a-rotation-on-the-iphone-without-the-device-autorotating/997064#997064), or have your view controller call a method in your view. Sample code for the latter:

```
// ViewController.m
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self.customView willRotateToOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

// CustomView.m
- (void)willRotateToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newOrientation {
    // Handle rotation
}
```

The view controller method is one you override; the view's method should be declared in a header.

**Update:**
Alternatively, you can find out the rotation in the controller's `viewWillAppear':

```
// ViewController.m
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    [self.customView willRotateToOrientation:[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
}
```

The method in your view will be called accordingly.

Comment: I've tried this, trouble is, `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` seems to be called after 'viewDidLoad' meaning that this is useless. So this method only works when rotating after a rotation and not as soon as the app loads up.

Comment: You could find out the orientation in `viewWillAppear` and make the call to the view then—see updated answer.

Comment: Turns out that the link to the other answer worked well. `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];` makes the if statement in my OP work a charm.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can to is to register for orientation notification from `NSNotificationCenter`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

...

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    // do things
}
```

This is however suboptimal since iPad may be laying flat on the table when app starts, and you'll get `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown` then. Been here, done that...

I ended up doing a trivial check like this:

```
BOOL landscape = self.bounds.size.width > self.bounds.size.height;
if (landscape)
    // landscape stuff
else
    // portrait stuff
```

But in my case the view changed aspect ratio upon rotation. If this is your case too, it should work fine.