# subview added to navigationbar ios

Tags: ios, ipad, subview, navbar

I have problems with displaying view as subview on navigationController.view on Ipad . I need to display view with transparent background on my viewController(with navBar),but while i change orientation my navBar become visible on foreGround of my view;
I created simple view based app.
Here code i added to project:

```
AppDelegate.h:

 UINavigationController *_navController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;

AppDelegate.m:

_navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = _navController;

ViewController.m:

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:view];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try pushing view to Navigation Controller

```
 YourAppDelegate *del = (YourAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[del.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

or

```
UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
 iVkViewController *overviewViewController = [[iVkViewController alloc] init];
 overviewViewController.title = @"First";
 [navigation pushViewController:overviewViewController animated:NO];
```

Comment: I do not have viewController. I need to display custom view above navController and navBar.I need fully cover display,cos when i pushViewController i push my view under the navBar.

Comment: okay so you want a custom bar ?have you tried tool bar? these lines may help u ..try along with uiview...
 UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [navCon setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
     self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: No. I have an app with navigationBar. I need to create UIView with transparent background,which will be added to viewController as subView. I need to do this all because i need to see elements from my viewController. Everything working fine until i rotate device. While rotation navBar become visible. I need hole screen to be under my view.

Comment: is your app orientation change set? check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779619/ipad-orientation-checking-uiview-class

Comment: Support of all orientations. I created project with single view. All code i added to it , is represented above in first my question.